# Calculating Density Function in Probability?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Given that:
$Y \sim \text{Exp}(j)$ and $X \sim \text{Uni}(a,b)$ independent from each other.
How may I calculate the density of $Z=Y-X$ knowing that:
$$
f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\mathrm dx.
$$

---

with your help I have calculated the density function for $-x$ which is

$$f_{-X}(-x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{b-a} &-x \in [a,b] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

And I got too: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_Y(y)f_{-X}(-x)dy$$

But how to continue from here? Plus how may I seperate the fields in which this is zero?

I know that:
$$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} &y >=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

---

**Update:** I got

$f_Z(z)$= 0 if $y<0$ or $x<-b$ or $x>-a $

else $1/{b-a}$

**My my book has a totally different Answer:**

if $z<-b$ then $0$

if $z>-a$ then $\dfrac {e^{- \lambda(a+z)}-e^{- \lambda(b+z)}}{b-a}$

else $\dfrac {1- e^{- \lambda(b+z)}}{b-a}$

Comment: change the variables and then integrate

Comment: Can someone kindly help with this one? is everything clear with my question? I have been trying for hours and no result

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [X-Y\leqslant c]&=\int_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x-y\leqslant c\}}f_X(x)f_Y(y)\mathop{}\!d (x,y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_Y(y)\left(\int_{(-\infty ,c+y]}f_X(x)\mathop{}\!dx\right)\mathop{}\!d y\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_Y(y)F_X(c+y)\mathop{}\!d y
\end{align*}
$$

Can you follow from here?

Comment: Can you kindly continue in the same method I started?

Comment: @White Im not sure what to do with $f_{-X}(-x)$ or what you are doing, instead try to follow the general procedure, that is $$\Pr [G(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)\leqslant c]=\Pr [(X_1,\ldots ,X_n)\in G^{-1}((-\infty ,c])]=\int_{G^{-1}((-\infty ,c])}\prod_{k=1}^n f_{X_n}(x_n)\mathop{}\!d (x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$$ where $X_1,\ldots ,X_n$ are independent and $G$ is any Lebesgue measurable function

Comment: I want it to be used with knowing that: (the sentence given by the question)