# How my professor made the following conclusion?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, density-function

**Update:** The suggested Answer didn't solve the problem

**Note:** This question can be solved without knowing probability at all. (all you need is the bold text)

Today my lecturer wrote the following on board:

[image]

**where the text in red specefies for which values the multiplication under integral sign **isn't** zero.**

I understand that we need to split into conditions:

1. where $\max\{0,z+a\}=0$ which means: $z<-a$
2. where $\max\{0,z+a\}=z+a$ which means: $z>-a$

but in the first condition where did we get $-b<=z$ from? I understand that without it something will be wrong since for all values the integral will not be 0 (while we know from the text in red that for some it's zero for sure) but I don't understand where it specifically came from...

I have been thinking on this for hours.

Comment: That strange word in bottom right means "else"

Comment: So, $Y$ and $X$ are exponential and uniform rv.s. And you are looking for the distribution of their difference?

Comment: Same recent questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3979063/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3975018/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom how it's the same? did you read my question? Here I am asking where the b came from

Comment: @d.k.o. yes but my main question focuses about the b here

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @WhiteForce What is the support of $f_x$?

Comment: what do you mean by support @copper.hat

Comment: Where is is non zero? On $[a,b]$?

Comment: what are the definitions of $f_\text{y}$ and $f_{-\text{x}}$? The  $b$ has to come from the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $f_{-\text{x}}$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like $Y \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $X \sim \text{Unif}(a,b)$. In that case $Y \geq 0$ and $a \leq X \leq b$. So $Y-X \geq -b$. Thus $f_{Y-X}(z)=0$ when $z <-b$.

Another way to think about it is combining the inequality $y \geq 0$ with the inequality $z+b \geq y$ gives $z+b \geq 0$, so $z \geq -b$.

Comment: The red inequality implies that both $0 \leq y$ and $y \leq z+b$ and so $0 \leq z+b$.

Comment: But if you look at 1 and 2 which I wrote they don't include this requirement (the one you said) my main point is why you took specially: ≥0  with the inequality +≥ while they are many many more combinations on the input.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In the case $z \leq -a$, i.e., $\max(0,z+a)=0$, the inequality in red simplifies to $0 \leq y \leq z+b$. Thus the integral in $y$ goes from $y=0$ to $y=z+b$, and this formula is only valid when $z \geq -b$ and $z \leq -a$. Put another way, when $z<-b$ we have $f_{-X}(z-y)=0 \neq \frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: "and this formula is only valid when ≥− and ≤−." this is the problem for me how did you conclude this. what is "this formula" and why it's valid only for those 2 cases? The only requirement we had in this path was ≤−

Comment: "Put another way, when <− we have −(−)=0" why this is correct too? why z-y isn't in [a,b] in this case?

Comment: In your main answer you mentioned: "Thus −()=0 when <−." but I don't have −() but −(-y)....

Comment: @WhiteForce The inequality $\max(0,z+a) \leq z \leq z+b$ must *always* hold, otherwise one of the two densities is equal to zero. So it's incorrect to say "the only requirement we had in this path was $z \leq -a$." You must have $z \leq -a$ *as well as* $\max(0,z+a) \leq z \leq z+b$.